# Calculated MySQL result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, calculation

I have a database of MMA fighters and their fights, stored in two tables: **fighter** and **fight**.

I want to query the database with a given figher id and get a result in rows like this:

```
Result | Record | Weight| Opponent| Opponent Record | Opponent Weight | Method | Date | Round | Time
```

The 4 last columns are pretty straight forward, but the other columns are tricky since I don't know if the given fighter id is fighter1 or fighter2:

*Result* should be taken from **fight.winner**, which has the values "fighter1", "fighter2", "TBD", "D" or "NC". The result needs to be calculated based on if the given fighter id is fighter1 or fighter2, so it shows either "W", "L", "TBD", "D" or "NC".

*Record* and *Opponent Record* should be taken from **fight.fighter1_record_after_result** or **fight.fighter2_record_after_result**, depending on if the given fighter id is fighter1 or fighter2.

*Weight* and *Opponent Weight* should be taken from **fight.fighter1_weight** or **fight.fighter2_weight**, depending on if the given fighter id is fighter1 or fighter2.

*Opponent* should be taken from **fighter.name**. Who should be regarded opponent, depends on wether the given fighter id is fighter1 or fighter2.

Data structure and sample data at DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5LjJqEM6yMYuShZybcsrJ5/0

Comment: please add data only as text, and a dbfiddle example is always appreciated

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know of DB Fiddle. Please see link in updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union all` might come handy here: instead of implementing complicated conditional logic in a single query, we can combine the result sets of two queries, that seach for the targer fighter in either column `fighter1` or column `fighter2`:

```
select
    case t.winner
        when 'fighter1' then 'W'
        when 'fighter2' then 'L'
        else t.winner
    end result,
    t.fighter1_record_after_result record,
    t.fighter1_weight weight,
    r.name opponent,
    t.fighter2_record_after_result oppononed_record,
    t.fighter2_weight opponent_weight,
    t.method,
    t.date,
    t.round,
    t.time
from fight t
left join fighter r on r.id = t.fighter2
where t.fighter1 = 64
union all
select
    case t.winner
        when 'fighter2' then 'W'
        when 'fighter1' then 'L'
        else t.winner
    end,
    t.fighter2_record_after_result,
    t.fighter2_weight,
    r.name,
    t.fighter1_record_after_result,
    t.fighter1_weight,
    t.method,
    t.date,
    t.round,
    t.time
from fight t
left join fighter r on r.id = t.fighter1
where t.fighter2 = 64
```

Both parameters should be given the value of the fighter that you are generating the report for.

Comment: Does this query need for me to supply an id for both fighter1 and fighter2? I can only supply one fighter id. See DB fiddle link in my updated question. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RawlandHustle: yes the query expects the id of one fighter only (but it appears twice in the query).